# why does this regex not work?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string with a java regex and I cannot succeed. I'm pretty new to java and with most of my experience being linux based regex, I've had no success. Can someone help me?

Below are the codes that Im using.

The regex is-

```
//vod//final\_\d{0,99}.\d{0,99}\\-Frag\d{0,99}
```

The line that I'm trying to match is

```
/vod/final_1.3Seg1-Frag1
```

where I want 1.3, 1 and 1 to be wildcarded.

Someone please help me out... :(

Comment: I really wonder - you're NOT escaping the dot `.` character, and you've got `{0,99}` - is this supposed to check for 0-99 digits? or is it supposed to be the numbers `0` to `99`?

Comment: It is supposed to check for numbers upto 100, I guess.

Comment: /vod/final_(.*)-Frag(\\d+) This seems to work

Comment: then that would be `(100|\d\d?)` instead of `\d{0,99}`, which will allow any number from `0` to `100`, but would require at least a single digit

Comment: then if you want to allow floating point numbers, you'd want something like  `(1?\d\d?(\.\d)` for `1.3` or `0` or `0.5` or `100.2` or `75` - would you want to allow `5.` or `2.456` or `2.4.67.3`?

Comment: I want to allow for just a single decimal place, numbers like 1.3 0.75 0.5 and 0.25 for example.

Comment: `(100|\d\d?(\.\d+)?)` should match whole numbers 0-100 (e.g. `0`, `1`, `22`, `96`, `100`), and numbers 0-99 with any number of digits afterward (`0.1`, `72.221`, `99.662534`, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `Seg1` part. Also you are escaping characters that need not to be escaped. Try out this regexp: `/vod/final_\\d+\\.\\d+Seg1-Frag\\d+`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "/vod/final_\\d+\\.\\d+Seg\\d+-Frag\\d+" );
```

Notes: To protect special characters, you can use `Pattern.quote()`

When running into problems like this, start with a simple text and pattern and build from there. I.e. first try to match `/`, then `/vod/`, then `/vod/final_1`, etc.

Comment: not sure if you have inside knowledge, but `{0,99}` is not the same as `+` in two ways: both the upper and lower limits

Comment: @CodeJockey I was just using place holders there, so I guess its ok :) Thanks, all of you.!

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping too much. Don't escape /, _, -.

Something like:

```
/vod/final_\d{0,99}.\d{0,99}-Frag\d{0,99}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
/\/vod\/final\_\d{0,99}.\d{0,99}Seg\d-Frag\d{0,99}
```

Also, here's what I used to edit the regex you provided above: http://rubular.com/

It says it's for ruby, but it also mentions that it works for java too.